# Python script to extract strings and ints between xml tags

Tags: python, xml

I need help extracting Things between XML tags. 
For example:

```
 <TimeStamp>DT#2019-08-27-08:20:51</TimeStamp>' ,  '<UserName>admin</UserName>' ,  '<Generator>SG-22-6500</Generator>' ,  '<GenFreq>20</GenFreq>' ,  '<MaxForce>10000</MaxForce>', '<MaxPower>6500</MaxPower>,
```

And now i want to have the values Dates and strings between the XML tags. The Output i wish for would be:

```
2019-08-27-08:20:51,admin,SG-22-6500,20,10000
```

and if there isnt anything between the tags, just print n.A for example.

i already tried the libary XML.etree, but i think my Problem is, my values do not come from a XML file…

Best regards!

Answer (score 1):

If you have a large XML, I would recommend [Beautiful Soup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/)

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bsoup
[bsoup(x).text for x in xml_list]
```

Alternatively, if you just need to pull out the text from a single Tag instead of a large file, try using a regular expression.

```
import re
[re.sub('<.*?>','',x) for x in xml_list]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `split`:

```
xml_var = '<TimeStamp>DT#2019-08-27-08:20:51</TimeStamp>'
xml_inner = xml_var.split('<TimeStamp>')[1].split('</TimeStamp>')[0]
print(xml_inner)
```

Will return whatever's between the `TimeStamp` tag. No need to over-engineer anything.

Answer (score 0):

You can use builtin xml parser

```py
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

x = [
    "<TimeStamp>DT#2019-08-27-08:20:51</TimeStamp>",
    "<UserName>admin</UserName>",
    "<Generator>SG-22-6500</Generator>",
    "<GenFreq>20</GenFreq>",
    "<MaxForce>10000</MaxForce>",
    "<MaxPower>6500</MaxPower>",
]

for i in x:
    tree = ET.ElementTree(ET.fromstring(i)).getroot()
    print(tree.text)
```

Prints

```
DT#2019-08-27-08:20:51
admin
SG-22-6500
20
10000
6500
```

Comment: I think i forgot to Say, that my Input is a list of tuples i extraxted from a csv file. 
so the Input in the variable x should be a Parameter that contains the list of These XML Things.

Comment: Just add one outer loop `for x in rows` before `for i in x:`

Comment: can i just somehow print the complete list into your x ,so not in just in the console? 
so that my x contains all the strings that i could use the rest of your Code.

Comment: You said you have a list of tuples. I assume it is something like `myxmls = [('xml1', 'xml2'), ('xml3', 'xml4')]`. Than just do `for x in myxmls: for i in x: do something`

Comment: i hope it is the same as you think. 
in my variable "values", the complete list is saved. i extracted the list from the csv file. 

so the Output of values is: '<XML1>abc<XML1>,'<XML2>efg<XML2>'... and so on. +